# Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation after integrating firebase

Tags: android, firebase, singleton, app-manager

I am getting this error:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Logcat:

```
05-21 01:25:46.136 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase D/ANRAppManager: !!! It is not under singleton mode, U can't use it. !!!
05-21 01:25:46.139 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                 at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
                                                                 at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
                                                                 at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
                                                                 at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
                                                                 at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1255)
                                                                 at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:691)
                                                                 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
05-21 01:25:46.143 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
05-21 01:25:46.143 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
05-21 01:25:46.143 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
05-21 01:25:46.143 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
05-21 01:25:46.143 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
05-21 01:25:46.143 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
05-21 01:25:46.144 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1255)
05-21 01:25:46.144 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err:     at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:691)
05-21 01:25:46.144 18093-18115/com.myapp.firbase W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
```

dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @Dhruv Added code, pls check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Finally I found the solution :)

This because I'm specifying `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0` as a dependency. I'm bringing in literally all of Google Play services - which is a lot!

In my case, I added below dependencies instead of `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
```

This can find a full list [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing occurring in my code.  The error says it all "Caught a RuntimeException..."

As it turns out, my code was throwing an exception that I wasn't catching.